# Quick way to find the duplicate cell in a certain column of data frame in python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

Given a data frame `df` in the following form:

```
item        attr
1           {1, 2, 3, 4}
2           {2, 4, 3, 2, 10}
3           {4, 37}
4           {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

I want to find the item-pair with same `attr`, like, `item 1` and `item 2`. Please notice that the `df` has `200,000` items totally. And I want a fastest way to find them. Do you know how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `attr` is a columns of `set`s?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes it is

Comment: Do you think pair `3,4` with `item` `1,2` and `1,2`, `2,3`.... in `item` `1, 4` ?

Comment: What is desired output from sample?

Comment: @jezrael The `item` with the same `attr`, i.e, whose set are same, are the pairs I want to find. So in the sample, `item 1` and `item 4` should be found

Comment: @jezrael Any form of output that can let me know `item 1` and `item 4` are pairs is acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert `set` to `tuple` and then [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html). Last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':[1,2,3,4],
                  'attr':[set({1, 2, 3, 4}),set({2, 4, 3, 2, 10}),
                          set({4, 37}), set({1, 2, 3, 4})]})

print (df)
            attr  item
0   {1, 2, 3, 4}     1
1  {3, 10, 2, 4}     2
2        {4, 37}     3
3   {1, 2, 3, 4}     4

df.attr = df.attr.apply(tuple)
print (df)
            attr  item
0   (1, 2, 3, 4)     1
1  (3, 10, 2, 4)     2
2        (4, 37)     3
3   (1, 2, 3, 4)     4

df1 = df.item.groupby(df['attr']).agg(['nunique', 'unique'])
df1 = df1[df1['nunique'] == 2]
print (df1)
              nunique  unique
attr                         
(1, 2, 3, 4)        2  [1, 4]
```

Another solution if there are only one or pair values in `DataFrame` with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':[1,2,3,4],
                  'attr':[set({1, 2, 3, 4}),set({4, 37}),
                          set({4, 37}), set({1, 2, 3, 4})]})

print (df)
           attr  item
0  {1, 2, 3, 4}     1
1       {4, 37}     2
2       {4, 37}     3
3  {1, 2, 3, 4}     4

df.attr = df.attr.apply(tuple)


df1 = df[df.duplicated('attr', keep=False)]
df1 = df1.groupby('attr')['item'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
print (df1)
(1, 2, 3, 4)    [1, 4]
(4, 37)         [2, 3]
Name: item, dtype: object
```

EDIT by comment:

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) for reshaping:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':[1,2,3,4,5],
                  'attr1':[set({1, 2, 3, 4}),set({4, 37}),set({4, 37}), 
                           set({1, 2, 3, 4}), set({4,8})],
                  'attr2':[set({1, 2 }),set({4, 37}),
                           set({4, 3}), set({1, 2}), set({4,8})]})

print (df)
          attr1    attr2  item
0  {1, 2, 3, 4}   {1, 2}     1
1       {4, 37}  {4, 37}     2
2       {4, 37}   {3, 4}     3
3  {1, 2, 3, 4}   {1, 2}     4
4        {8, 4}   {8, 4}     5

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='item', value_name='attr').drop('variable', axis=1)
df.attr = df.attr.apply(tuple)
print (df)
   item          attr
0     1  (1, 2, 3, 4)
1     2       (4, 37)
2     3       (4, 37)
3     4  (1, 2, 3, 4)
4     5        (8, 4)
5     1        (1, 2)
6     2       (4, 37)
7     3        (3, 4)
8     4        (1, 2)
9     5        (8, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's great!

Comment: But I still have a question... Could you please let this be more general? So it also works when there are more than one column of `attr`, like `attr1` and `attr2`?

Comment: `set` in `DataFrames` are not obvious, so this answer is complicated. I think you need reshape to one column `attr` if there are more columns `attr1`, `attr2`... and then apply this answer.

Comment: Finally there are 66 pairs of same item. But indeed I wanna find the top 100 similar pairs by jaccard similarity. I thought there are more than 100 pairs of items are same among 200,000 but there aren't. Do you have any idea to quickly calculate all the similarity of the items?

Comment: I think you can create new question, because in statistics I can not help you very well. Unfortunately. :(

Comment: Or maybe you need [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score.html) and this library I never used, so I hope some `scikit` user can help you.